# How to make AlertDialog to display anywhere in android app?

Tags: android

I wanna create android app which after 30 second will display to me AlertDialog 
I did it but i wanna make AlertDialog will display any where in android for example in home of android.
like this http://www.papktop.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/Popup-Notifier-1.jpg
 it is my code (main Activity )

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    mTextField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mTextField);
}
public void show(View view) {

    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialog.setMessage("Nek Test");
    // alertDialog.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.notification_image));
    alertDialog.setTitle("Reminder");
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Got it", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            mTextField.setText("done!");
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }.start();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For show a dialog outside the app, for example over the Home you need to put this permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Create a service like this:

```
public class AlertService extends Service {

private static Context context;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    context = this;

    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertDialog.setMessage("Nek Test");
    alertDialog.setTitle("Reminder");
    /**ADD THIS FOR DISPLAY THE ALERT ANYWHERE*/
    alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Got it", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }
        public void onFinish() {
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }.start();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

}//End class
```

And finally start the service from activity:

```
startService(new Intent(this, AlertService.class));
```

and add this line into the "application" tag in the manifest:

```
<service android:name=".AlertService" />
```

Comment: I am sorry i have error  alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT); blomle with getWindows

Comment: Sorry. I do not understand.

Comment: I am sorry not blomle problem

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this :

1- Implement a service that will start in the main activity and in the service execute a timer, and whenever the timer finishes it will call a broadcast receiver and this receiver will trigger the showing of the alert dialogue.

2- You could use otto : http://square.github.io/otto/
In otto you have to register every activity to otto and unregister onDestroy off course. The timer has to be in an asynctask and on the post execute you post a certain result. Then you subscribe the onAsyncTaskResult in each activity and trigger the alert dialogue there.

3- You also use otto but this time do not subscrib to onAsyncTaskResult and instead of posting in the onPostExecute send a broadcast. Have a broadcast listener ready and on receive show the alert dialogue

Answer (score 0):

This code works best for me without any errors

```
public class AlertService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertService.this).create();
        alertDialog.setMessage("Nek Test");
        alertDialog.setTitle("Reminder");
        alertDialog.setButton("Got it", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        /**ADD THIS FOR DISPLAY THE ALERT ANYWHERE*/
        alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
        alertDialog.show();
        return flags;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```